# can not set gelocation permission in jxbrowser- java

Tags: java, swing, google-maps, geolocation, jxbrowser

I have a java app that **show user location with [jxbrowser](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/)** .
(we print location in browser console and get it with console listener in java)

In my ***getLocation.java*** :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       final Browser browser = new Browser();
       BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);

       JFrame frame = new JFrame("as");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.add(browserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       frame.setSize(900, 500);
       frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       browser.setPermissionHandler(new PermissionHandler() {
        @Override
        public PermissionStatus onRequestPermission(PermissionRequest request) {
            if (request.getPermissionType() == PermissionType.GEOLOCATION) {
                return PermissionStatus.GRANTED;
            }
            return PermissionStatus.DENIED;
        }
        });
       browser.addConsoleListener(new ConsoleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(ConsoleEvent message) {
            System.out.println(message.getMessage());

        }
       });
       browser.loadURL("C://Users/aa/Desktop/Advance Java Projects/Snap/src/views/map/getlocation.html");
   }
```

And in my ***getlocation.html***:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
   <style type="text/css">
       html { height: 100% }
       body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <script>
      getLocation()
        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            } else {
                console.log("poof browser!");
            }
        }
        function showPosition(position) {
          console.log(position.coords.latitude);
          console.log(position.coords.longitude);
        }
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

But when i run **my app i have no response**!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the [security](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only) restrictions in Chromium 50 and higher, geolocation doesn't work for `file:///` URI. You must put a web page that works with the Geolocation API on a web server and access the web page through HTTPS protocol. Otherwise it won't work.